# Load images below the fold page when scrolling?

Tags: image, load

I need to load images below the fold page when scrolling. 
When the page is loaded just the images above the fold page should be loaded. Then, when scrolling down the fold the reached image should load.

I took a look to the jquery Lazyload plugin, but isn't working with new browsers version because is not longer updated...

Answer (score 0):

visit this site http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/imageloader/

The ImageLoader Utility allows you as an implementer to delay the loading of images on your web page until such a time as your user is likely to see them. This can improve your overall pageload performance by deferring the loading of some images that are not immediately visible at the time the page first renders. Because images are often the heaviest components of a given page, deferring the loading of some images can yield a marked improvement in the way the page "feels" to your user.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jquery lazyload github repository](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload) and the [enabled_gazillion](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_lazyload/blob/master/enabled_gazillion.html) example, you will see reference to "real image url is stored in *original* property."

This means, if you use this non-valid html, it will work as intended in new browsers.

```
<img src="transparent.gif" original="realimage.gif" />
```

I would prefer original was configurable or an html5 style data- attribute (so maybe I should create an issue or pull request).